# macOS Sierra - 1.5TB partition is gone after trying to merge two smaller preceding partitions

Tags: disk-utility, macos, recovery, data-recovery

Just used the *dreaded newer* Disk Utility to merge two smaller partitions. It seemed that the operation caused my main 1.5TB partition, last on the disk to reappear, empty, with the name of one of the smaller partitions.

Also a Recovery partition 600MB seems to have appeared and is now the last one on disk.

The old disk utility would never do this... I never asked for this recovery partition but here it is... I have a feeling that the merging went fine but it's the adding of the Recovery partition that screwed things up.

My files are there, I had about 1TB of data on it, about 2/3 of the space was occupied.

Any advice on how to recover from this? I plan to image the drive so I can dig into it safely.

Some details:

1. I deleted the empty 1.5tb partition in an effort to have test disk search the free space for info. Now it seems the larger partition is gone too.
2. The files I had on the main partition were very few and huge. There were about 7 files one was 287Gb and so on...

   ```
   diskutil list
    /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS 64 - 1                  64.0 GB    disk2s2

   sudo gpt -r show disk2
        start        size  index  contents
            0           1         PMBR
            1           1         Pri GPT header
            2          32         Pri GPT table
           34           6         
           40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640   125000000      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    125409640  3781619495         
   3907029135          32         Sec GPT table
   3907029167           1         Sec GPT header
   ```

Comment: @klanomath - Added it.

Comment: Do you remember the sizes of your older, smaller - now vanished - volumes? The Recovery HD is usually hidden, at the end of the disk and with a size of 650 MB but also gone. I assume the 64 GB is a second os x boot volume on the external disk and wasn't changed throughout your disk operations! Also: "My files are there, I had..." should be read/written as "My files are gone on the 1.5 TB partition..."?

Comment: @klanomath the disk is 2tb in size. It was partitioned in 5 parts, 64, 64, 320, 64 and 1536. What I tried to do was merge the second third and forth into one leaving the big one 1536 intact. The operation was a success and now I have 64, 448 and 1536 the only problem is that the 1536 partition has the same name as the preceding 64 one, just the name, the size location hasn't changed and is now empty, and the recovery partition which is now visible and last on disk.